# I have a grapefruit tree that has been given to me this month in Nov..I have to move the tree now..Will it kill the tree?

Tags: fruit-trees, transplanting

I have been given a grapefruit tree medium height with fruit on it A persimmon tree and a loquat tree with fruit on it. I have to get them now per the owners. If I trim these trees and take off the fruit now this time of year in November in the South, will they survive?? It's still in the 70s - 80s here in Alabama.

Comment: Doesn't really sound like you have much choice on the timing. Look up general advice on transplanting citrus and go for it - at most, you've wasted some labor if it fails. I can't really advise on citrus transplanting tricks, they live in pots and generally don't fruit here, even if the pots get dragged out for the summer months. So I mostly don't bother any more.

Comment: Welcome to teh site Elizabeth.  Since you have mentioned taking off the fruit, taking it off is not going to worsen their chances of surviving.  Also, you have three questions here.  This site works better with a single question at a time.  As it stands, it deters people from answering it unless they know about all 3 trees.

Comment: It all comes down to the roots. If you get 90% of the fine feeder rootsof a tree but cut the tap root, you have good chances of survival. Less than 75% and you do not. Buy a rooting stumilant liquid.

Comment: Trimming a tree doesn't harm it, unless you mean removing 90%. Harvesting fruit does not harm the tree. Moving a 3-year-old is one thing. Moving a 10-year-old requires a professional with expensive Vemeer apparatus.